# Connect a domain to a Django app deployed with google cloud

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dns

I made a Django app and deployed it with google app engine. It is working and I can indeed access it with the URL google is providing me.
I also have a domain name I bought on Ionos and I'd like to connect my domain to my Django app.
I'm pretty sure I should configure the DNS. But I can't find the parameters in google cloud platform that would allow me to do so. Anyone knows where to find the DNS parameters on google cloud platform ?
Thanks

Comment: Yes indeed ! thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've mapped your service to a custom domain in App Engine, you need to update your DNS records at your domain registrar. As a convenience, App Engine generates and displays the DNS records you need to enter.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#dns_update) is the documentation about how to get the DNS information in order to update it on your domain registrar.

Comment: Thx ! Worked like a charm